# Rails options for select send nil when no option selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in my rails app:

```
<%= select :object,
           :id,
           options_for_select(Hash[@object_list.map { |object| [object.name, object.id] }]),
           {:include_blank => 'Please select...'},
           {} %>
```

If no option is selected then in my controller I receive an empty string. 

How can I make the options for select send 'nil' value instead?

Comment: `nil if " "` on server side?

Comment: There are dozens of posts on SO with this question. One easy way is to use: https://github.com/rubiety/nilify_blanks or https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer

Comment: Please post the related controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve that by inserting `nil` in your list.

```
<%= select :object,
           :id,
           options_for_select(Hash[@object_list.map { |object| [object.name, object.id] }].merge({:0 => nil}), selected: 0) %>
```

Comment: This is close to what I wanted. You have to use 'merge', and set it as default, removing the include_blank. Edit it and I will mark it as accepted

Comment: @Dragos I have edited as per your request. Not tried though, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `before_action` callback for your controller.

```
class SomeController
  before_action :prepare_params

  private

  def prepare_params
    params[:your_param] = nil if params[:your_param].blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: This could be a suggestion, not the solution IMO.